# How to prove the existence and uniqueness of pde with Caputo fractional derivative in time

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, fractional-calculus, fractional-sobolev-spaces, fractional-differential-equations

For any $\beta>0$ we denote the Riemann-Liouville fractional integral operator of order $\beta$ by

$$ I^{\beta}(f)(t)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(\beta)} \int_{0}^{t}(t-\tau)^{\beta-1} f(\tau) d \tau, \quad f \in L^{1}(0, T), \text { a.e. } t \in(0, T),$$

where $T>0$ and $\Gamma(\beta)=\int_{0}^{\infty} t^{\beta-1} e^{-t} d t$ is the Euler Gamma function.

The Caputo fractional derivative of order $\alpha \in(1,2)$ is given by
$$
\partial_{t}^{\alpha} f(t)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(2-\alpha)} \int_{0}^{t}(t-\tau)^{1-\alpha} \frac{d^{2} f}{d \tau^{2}}(\tau) d \tau
$$

Let the following equation:

$$ \partial_{t}^{\alpha} u(t,x) + A(u(t,x)) = f(t,x)$$
where $A$ is a differential operator non linear.

**The question is: How to prove the existence and uniqueness of this equation**

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: It is unlikely that anybody will be able to answer this as is. If you want any hope of an answer you need to provide more details: what do you know about $A$? What about $f$? In what region is your equation defined and what assumptions do you have on this region (e.g is it bounded with smooth boundary)? Are there intial/boundary conditions? In which functional space does $u$ live?